# Kali Linux login loop, ran out of disk space - can't update anything

Tags: kali-linux, vmware

I am currently running kali linux on VMware, I recently ran out of space and i decided to make a shared folder between my windows 10 host so i could get all the files i want to keep before wiping kali. I don't know if it has anything to do with the shared folder i created but now I'm stuck in a login loop. I have looked around and nothing is working. I have tried creating a new user, taking out the shared folder, giving my virtual machine more space. I have been told to update everything but i can't because i don't have enough space on the VM. I have tried all sorts of commands in the login terminal. Please can someone help me with this issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Grub menu offers a recovery mode, try to start this. Or attach a CD/DVD image of a live/rescue system to your VM and boot from this CD image.

You can change the size of the virtual disk image and the size of the partitions. See e.g https://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/

Comment: Thank you! I changed the size of the hard disk then was able to update everything and get out of the login loop. I really appreciate your reply, thanks again!!!!